Help in understanding proof for: There exists recursive $f$ such that for all $e$, if $R_e$ is well-founded then $f(e) \in O$ (G.E. Sacks book)
I am trying to read G.E. Sacks's book on Higher Recursion Theory. Let:
$$
R_e(x,y) \iff \{e\}(x,y) \text{ is defined }
$$
be the $e$th recursively enumerable binary relation. In Lemma 4.3, we have that there exists a recursive $f$ such that for all $e$, we have the following (where $O$ is Kleene's $O$).
$$
R_e \text{ is well-founded } \iff f(e) \in O
$$
The proof begins by defining $h$ as a total recursive function such that:
$$
R_{h(e,n)}(x,y) \iff R_e(x,y) \wedge R_e(x,n) \wedge R_e(y,n)
$$
Afterwards (using the recursion theorem), we get a total recursive $t$ such that:
$$
W_{t(e)} = \{f(h(e,n)) | n \leq \omega \} \text { (and $\emptyset$ if $R_e=\emptyset$) }
$$
where $f(e)=g(t(e))$ and $g$ is a function such that $g(e) \in O \iff W_e \subseteq O$ and $g(e) \in O \rightarrow |a| < |g(e)|$ for all $a \in W_e$ (as defined in Lemma 4.1).
But for completeness, I'll write $g$ here, where we have $g(e)=3\cdot 5^{s(e)}$ where $s(e)$ is as follows.
$$
\{s(e)\}(n+1) = \{s(e)\}(n) +_O 2^{\{r(e)\}(n+1)}
$$
And where $\{r(e)\}$ is a total function with range $W_e \cup \{1 \}$.
Now if $R_e$ is wellfounded, by transfinite induction, we do have $f(e) \in O$ given that for each $n$, we compute $|R_{h(e,n)}|$ and then do induction on $|R_e|$ - and have something similar to $\{r(e)\}$ above - as used in the function $\{s(e)\}$.
However, this assumes that we are able to compute $R_{h(e,n)}(x,y)$ for all $x,y < n$. However, $R_{h(e,n)}$ is only recursively enumerable whereas Lemma 4.1 above assumes that $\{r(e)\}$ is total. But am I right that since we are working with analytic sets, we could assume that we have an "answer" for the Kleene predicate $\exists w [T(R_{h(e,n)},w)]$ since this is an arithmetical predicate, whereas $O$ is $\Pi_1^1$ ? (i.e. given $\exists w [T(R_{h(e,n)},w)]$ we can form the corresponding total function $\{r(e)\}$ such that the range of $\{r(e)\}$ is $W_{R_{h(e,n)}} \cup 1$ if we are dealing with analytic sets ...)

no one's answering ... bounty's on the way ...

This answer has two parts:

In the proof summarized in the question, from Higher Recursion Theory by Gerald E. Sacks, why does the well-foundedness of $R_e$ imply that $f(e)\in\scr O?$

(Marked "Addendum".) How can one construct the recursive function $r$ in the following statement, which appears in Sacks's proof of Lemma 4.1 in the same book:
Let $r$ be a total recursive function such that
for all $e, \{r(e)\}$ is total and the range of $\{r(e)\}$ is $W_e\cup\{1\}.$



First, if anyone wants to look up the book by Sacks that this refers to, it's available online at
https://projecteuclid.org/eBooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631 
with free open access. OP's question pertains to Chapter I of the book.
But I'm trying to keep this answer as self-contained as possible, so let's start with the preliminaries:
If $R$ is a binary relation on $\omega,$ then the field of $R$ is the collection of all $x$ such that for some $y,$ we have $x R y$ or $y R x.$
$R$ is well-founded if every non-empty subset $S$ of the field of $R$ has an element $m\in S$ which is minimal in the sense that there is no $x\in S$ for which $xRm.$
If $R$ is well-founded and $a\in R,$ then we can define the height of $a$ to be the least ordinal which is greater than the height of $x$ for all $xRa.$ (Well-foundedness of $R$ is sufficient to allow this sort of definition by transfinite induction.)
The height of $R$ is the least ordinal greater than the height of all $x$ in the field of $R.$
Now, for any $n\lt\omega,$ define the binary relation $\mathrm {Pred}(R,n)$ to be $\{x\mid xRn\}$ with the ordering inherited from $R.$ (This is empty if $n$ is not in the field of $R.)$
Let $R_e$ be the $e^\text{th}$ recursively enumerable binary relation on $\omega$ (using a standard acceptable numbering of the partial recursive functions).
A recursive function $h$ is defined so that, for all $e,n\lt\omega,$
$$R_{h(e,n)} = \mathrm{Pred}(R_e,n).$$
From a previous lemma, we have a recursive function $g$ such that, for all $e\lt\omega,$
$$g(e)\in{\scr O}\text{ iff } W_e\subseteq\scr O$$
and
$$g(e)\in{\scr O}\implies (\forall x\in W_e)(|x|_{\scr O}\lt |g(e)|_{\scr O}).$$
Sacks then shows how to construct recursive functions $t$ and $f$ such that, for all $e\lt\omega,$
$$W_{t(e)}=\begin{cases}\emptyset,&\text{ if }R_e=\emptyset,\\
\{f(h(e,n)\mid n\lt\omega\},&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(e)=g(t(e)).$$

Now we're ready to show that, for all $e\lt\omega,$
$$R_e\text{ is well-founded}\implies f(e)\in{\scr O},$$
using transfinite induction on the height of $R_e.$ Here's how it works:
Suppose that $R_e$ is well-founded and that we know that the statement above is true for all r.e. binary relations shorter than $R_e.$ We need to show that the statement is then true for $R_e$ too.
If $R_e$ is empty, then $W_{t(e)}=\emptyset\subseteq\scr O,$ so $f(e)=g(t(e))\in\scr O.$
So assume $R_e$ is non-empty. Then, for every $n\lt\omega,$ $R_{h(e,n)}=\mathrm{Pred}(R_e,n)$ has height less than the height of $R_e.$ By the induction hypothesis, for each $n$ we have $f(h(e,n))\in{\scr O}.$
Since $W_{t(e)}=\{f(h(e,n))\mid n\lt\omega\}\subseteq \scr O,$ the basic property of $g$ yields that $f(e) = g(t(e))\in \scr O,$ completing the proof.

Addendum:
OP asked how to construct the recursive function $r$ in the following statement, which appears in Sacks's proof of Lemma 4.1:
Let $r$ be a total recursive function such that
for all $e, \{r(e)\}$ is total and the range of $\{r(e)\}$ is $W_e\cup\{1\}.$
This type of thing is often left for the reader to do, but it takes a bit of set-up to carry out the proof formally, since you need to use the s-m-n theorem to get the required uniformity.
Here's one way to do it:
Define a recursive function $f$ by setting
$$f(e,x,y) = \begin{cases}
x, &\text{ if the computation for }\{e\}(x)\text{ halts in fewer than }y\text{ steps,}\\
1, &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Let $\pi:\omega\times\omega\to\omega$ be a recursive pairing function, and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the corresponding projection functions, so that $\pi(x,y)=z$ iff both $x=\alpha(z)$ and $y=\beta(z).$ The functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are also recursive.
Define a recursive function $g$ by setting $g(e,x)=f(e,\alpha(x),\beta(x)).$
The s-m-n theorem tells us that there is a recursive function $s$ such that, for all $u, v,$ and $w,$
$\{s(u,v)\}(w)=\{u\}(v,w).$
Let $d$ be an index for the recursive function $g;$ that is, $\{d\}=g.$
Then we have $$\begin{align}\{s(d,e)\}(\pi(x,y)) &= \{d\}(e,\pi(x,y))\\&= g(e,\pi(x,y))\\&=f(e,x,y)\end{align}$$
for all $e, x,$ and $y.$
Finally define $r(e)=s(d,e).$ The function $r$ is then total recursive, and we have
$$\begin{align}\text{the range of }\{r(e)\}&= \{\{r(e)\}(x)\mid x\lt\omega\}\\
&= \{\{s(d,e)\}(x)\mid x\lt\omega\}\\
&=
\{\{s(d,e)\}(\pi(x,y))\mid x,y\lt\omega\}\\
&=\{f(e,x,y)\mid x,y\lt\omega,\}
\end{align}$$
which is the union of the two sets
$$\begin{align}A &= \{f(e,x,y)\mid x,y\lt\omega\text { and the computation of }\{e\}(x)\text{ halts in fewer than }y\text{ steps}\}\\
&=\{x\mid (\exists y)(\text {the computation of }\{e\}(x)\text{ halts in fewer than }y\text{ steps})\}\\
&=\{x\mid\text { the computation of }\{e\}(x)\text{ halts}\}\\
&=W_e
\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}B &= \{f(e,x,y)\mid x,y\lt\omega\text { and the computation of }\{e\}(x)\text{ does not halt in fewer than }y\text{ steps}\}\\
&=\{1\}.
\end{align}$$
For the last equality, note that:
$B\subseteq\{1\},$ since any $f(e,x,y)$ where the conditions are satisfied must equal $1,$
and
$\{1\}\subseteq B,$ since no computation can halt in fewer than $0$ steps, so, for any $x,$ $f(e,x,0)=1$ must be in $B.$
So the range of $\{r(e)\}$ is $W_e\cup\{1\},$ as desired.
Finally, for any $e,$ $\{r(e)\}$ is total, since
$$\begin{align}
\{r(e)\}(x) &= \{s(d,e)\}(x)\\
&= \{d\}(e,x) \\
&= g(e,x) \\
&= f(e,\alpha(x),\beta(x)),
\end{align}$$
which is defined for all $x.$
This completes the proof.

thank you ! - what I want to ask is Lemma 4.1, i.e. the lemma for $g(e)$ that you used above. Sacks mentions there that $g(e)$ is an "infinite sum" of $W_e$, and that $g(e)$ uses a total recursive function $r$ such that for all $e$, we have the range of ${r(e)}$ as $W_e \cup 1$. How can we form this $r$ ?

I guess we can have something like ${r(e)} = e_0^{W_e}$ for some $e_0$ such that if $e_0^{W_e}(x)=n$ then $n \in W_e$. My question is... can we can use $W_e$ as an oracle for $e_0$ ? - I am guessing this is okay since $W_e$ can be defined using an arithmetical formula.

I’ll take a look at that in the next few days, whenever I have time. As I recall, you use $+_O$ repeatedly, in whatever order the recursive enumeration is in. Then you take the limit of those ($3\cdot5^e$ where ${e}$ enumerates the partial $+_O$-summands).

okay much appreciated thanks

on the other hand ... I just remembered that $W_e$ is r.e. iff it is the range of some total recursive function ...

It's just slightly trickier than that suggests.  For one thing, only non-empty r.e. sets are the range of a total recursive function.  Also (and this is the slightly tricky part), you need to show this fact about r.e. sets uniformly — that is, you need to show how to compute an index for a recursive function whose range is some r.e. set from an index for a partial recursive function whose domain is that set; that's what the recursive function $r$ is doing. I just added an addendum to the answer to show how to do this formally.

awesome ! thanks !
